# File downloading using splash with button click

Tags: python, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I have a spider used to scrape some data along with a pdf file. Everything is done except the pdf. There is no direct src for the pdf to download in to the file_urls field.
The html looks like this

```
<a onclick="document.forms[0].target ='_blank';" id="main_0_body_0_lnkDownloadBio" href="javascript:__doPostBack('main_0$body_0$lnkDownloadBio','')">Download full <span class="no-wrap">bio <i class="fa fa-angle-right" data-nowrap-cta=""></i></span></a>
```

It seems some javascript click method is working instead of src. When we click on the this, it will open a new window with option to download. Now I planned to use splash request along with lua script. Here is the code

```
class DataSpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = config.NAME
allowed_domains = [config.DOMAIN]

def start_requests(self):

    for url in config.START_URLS:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_data)

def parse_data(self, response):
    script = """
    function main(splash)
        local url = splash.args.url
        assert(splash:go(url))
        assert(splash:wait(1))

        -- go back 1 month in time and wait a little (1 second)
        assert(splash:runjs("document.getElementById('DownloadBio').click()"))
        assert(splash:wait(1))

        -- return result as a JSON object
        return {
            html = splash:html(),
        }
    end
    """

    response = json.loads(response.text)
    res = response['people']
    for index, i in enumerate(res[1]):
        first_name = res[index]['name']
        last_name = res[index]['lastname']
        location = res[index]['location']
        link = res[index]['pageurl']
        link = config.HOST + link
        item = ProtoscraperItem(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, title=title, location=location, link=link)

        # This request is for the detail page and there is more info and pdf.

        request = SplashRequest(link, self.parse_details, meta={
            'splash': {
                'args': {'lua_source': script, 'wait': 30, 'timeout': 40},
                'endpoint': 'execute',
            },)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        request.meta['link'] = link
        yield request

def parse_details(self, response):

    # what to do here
```

So here I'm clicking the anchor tag to execute the javscript. And I think it is working, but nothing is getting downloaded. What I'm missing here. Is it possible to specify the path to download?. I think this is possible with selenium but how can I do this with splash and lua?

Comment: What's in `response.body` in `parse_details` method?

Comment: I just checked on another site with a PDF download and it seems splash won't work you. So what you need to do is see what kind of request is initiated when the form is submitted in normal browser and try to simulate the request directly

Comment: @TarunLalwani through a normal browser the form submit initiating a post request and opens a new tab with pdf. This is browser preview before download or print any document. 
I have submitted the same form from code but I'm getting the same html as response text. Can you tell me how can I send this request and process?

Comment: @TomášLinhart I'm getting the same html where download button exists as response.

Comment: Hard to say without looking at the page, this is a site specific approach. Can't say much

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the click button i believe that it is calling "__doPostBack" function in ASP.net. When you click that submit button the form[0] is submited with certain values. You need to inspet the page for all the elements being submitted with the form submit.

Argument needed for doing this is

> __EVENTTARGET,
>
> __EVENTARGUMENT
>
> __VIEWSTATE
>
> __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR
>
> __EVENTVALIDATION

maybe more, usually these arguments are set as hidden values in the form. (Please verify it in your webpage)

```
 arguments = {'__EVENTTARGET': 'main_0$body_0$lnkDownloadBio',
                 '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
                 '__VIEWSTATE': viewstate,
                 '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': viewstategen,
                 '__EVENTVALIDATION': eventvalid,
                 'search': '',
                 'filters': '',
                 'score': ''
              }
    
    HEADERS = {
                'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) 
                 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
                 Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36',
                'Accept': 'text / html, application / xhtml + xml, 
                 application / xml;q = 0.9, image / webp, image / apng, * 
                 / *;q = 0.8'
               }
    
    data = urllib.urlencode(arguments)
    r = requests.post(submitin_url, data, allow_redirects=False, headers=HEADERS)
    
    with open(some_filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

I had similar kind of work with my project and i have done like this. Send the form values and arguments using Python Request. The response will be the file which you are trying to download. Write it in to a file and make sure the extension is correct. I hope it will help for you.